# Load mark doesn't disappear after loading in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

In my rails project sometimes chrome doesn't stop showing "loading circle icon" even after finished a loading. At least it appears all HTML elements are shown and JS works fine.

[image]

It doesn't happen in local development. Neither with Firefox and Safari in server environment.

It happens only with chrome in server environments.

What should I do to determine the cause of the problem?